# Dynamic content in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I'd like to add a dynamic list of persons to a Shopify site, and would appreciate directions on how to accomplish this, or where to find resources.

The data I'd like to add is organised as follows:
1   person (name, photo, description, website, email, city etc.)
2   country (name, flag)
3   certificate (name, level of expertise, date of certification etc.)
•   each person has one country.
•   each person has one or more certificates.
•   there's no connection between this data and products on the Shopify site.

Data is entered and edited by admin only.
Persons are displayed on a page grouped by country, and grouped by certificate within country.

I did some PHP, MySQL, HTML and CSS in the past, not on a pro level, but somehow "good enough" when I had some basic tutorial to follow and expand on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a blog, then a tag for each country in the articles (one article per person) so you may get a "homepage" for each country and a global one.

To structure datas for each person/article, I'd use metafields: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/metafield

Like this, it shouldn't be too complicated to code pages as you like.

Comment: This is so cool! No fancy coding…